# jQuery: Building a form on modal with role field as select and user field as other. Have to disable role if it is selected on other select

Tags: javascript, jquery

Writing a dynamic form which updates the role of a user. There are 2 role leader(which can be given to 1 person) and member user and a team consist of 4 members(including leader). By form, they select who gets to be leader and rest as a member. So in the form which I am binding by jQuery uses select dropdown for roles with 2 option leader and member. How am i suppose to disable if in any select leader has been picked. I can restrict this validation at the backend site but I also want if this thing can be done at frontend side it will be better.

Below is the snippet:

```
function updateRole(){
  $('#update-table-body').empty();
    let body='';
   for(var i=0;i<members.length;i++)
                {     
                  body+='<tr>'; 
                  body+='<th><input type="hidden" name="member'+i+'" value="'+members[i].id+'"/>'+members[i].name+'</th>';
                  body+='<td><div class="control"><div class="select">\
                    <select id="role_'+i+'" name="role'+i+'" onchange="dissRole()">\
                      <option hidden></option>\
                      <option value="1">Leader</option>\
                      <option value="2">Member</option>\
                    </select></div></div></td>';    
                  body+='</tr>';
                }
        body+='<input type="hidden" id="count" name="count" value="'+members.length+'"/>';
  $('#update-table-body').append(body);
  $('.modal').addClass('is-active');
 }
```

and

```
function dissRole(){
    $(this)
        .siblings('select')
        .children('option[value="1"]')
        .prop('disabled', true)
        .siblings().removeAttr('disabled');
}
```

Edit 1: There is other select also in the normal HTML template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the `dissRole()` function and giving select a similar id's here is the working answer

```
function dissRole(){
     // List of ids that are selected in all select elements
        var selected = new Array();

        // Get a list of the ids that are selected
        $('select[id^="role_"] option:selected').each(function()
        {
            selected.push($(this).val());

        });

        // Walk through every select option and enable if not
        // in the list and not already selected
        $('select[id^="role_"] option').each(function()
        {
            if (!$(this).is(':selected') && $(this).val() != '' && $(this).val() != '2')
            {
                var shouldDisable = false;
                for (var i = 0; i < selected.length; i++)
                {
                  //alert(selected.length);
                    if (selected[i] == $(this).val())
                        shouldDisable = true;
                }


                $(this).removeAttr('disabled', 'disabled');
                if (shouldDisable)
                {
                    $(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                }
            }
        });
}
```